# install glove_python on windows

Tags: python, windows, gcc, mingw32

I tried to install `glove_python` package (https://github.com/maciejkula/glove-python) and I  keep getting the same error like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36587622/glove-python-on-windows).
 
I tried using the mingw32 compiler, and I got the following error.
`glove/glove_cython.c:262:17: fatal error: omp.h: No such file or directory
 compilation terminated.
 error: command 'C:\\Anaconda2\\Scripts\\gcc.bat' failed with exit status 1`
I even tried using `TDM` but again I'm getting the following error.
`gcc: error: libgomp.spec: No such file or directory
error: command 'c:\\TDM-GCC-64\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1`